# How and when would you be using tabIndex=0 on your Button element?

Tags: javascript, dom, button, dom-events, keyboard-events

I'm currently working on my React app and trying to make multiple buttons, that I have there, to be responsive on `click` and `keydown` events. Browsing through Stack Overflow and some YouTube tutorials I noticed that they have been using `tabIndex=0` property on their buttons in combination with some sort of `key` event. I wonder why is it done this way? And how and when would you be using `tabIndex=0` on your `Button` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabindex` as you may have already discovered, allows elements to receive keyboard focus, ie navigated by pressing tab. The reason the value of tabIndex is `0`, is that it doesn't change tab order, therefore maintaining the tab order to the logical flow of the page

Setting the index value greater than 1, defines a specified tab order, **which is not ideal because:**

1. Tab order cannot be changed by rearranging elements in the content.
2. Screen readers, for visually impaired users, will read the elements with `tabindex` in the order of their values, which could be in different order compared to what's visually presented in the page.

Therefore when using tabindex, make sure to set it's value to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

tabindex is used for keyboard navigation. For example for people that are using screenreaders. tabindex=0 determines the first element will be focused on, after you press the tab key.